# write in another jtextfield after

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

I have 3 JTextfields.

1. The first one has the price.
2. Second one has the option.
3. Third is empty.

I have to write in the empty JTextfield after few condition.

I mean if option = full, I have to write in the empty textfield the value in first textfield+value in first text field*50%.

e.g

First text field: 50

Second text field: full

Third text field: 50+(50*50%)

How to fill the third JTextField?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: How about registering an event listener to the textfield's changed event?

Comment: booking for a trip. price depend on  option selected (full/half)
the user select the option and he gets the amount to pay in third text field

Comment: Use A ComboBox In Place of a text Field. The Users will have to type in the value `FULL` or `HALF` if you user a textfield. This cannot be reliedd on because of typing errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in Button action like this to achieve your task.

```
if(secondText.getText().equals("full")
{
int firstTextFieldValue=Integer.parseInt(firstTextField.getText());
int result=firstTextFieldValue+(firstTextFieldValue*50);
thirdTextField.setText(result+"");
}
```

The above code will do the operation.